# htaccess redirect with drupal and gallery on dreamost

Tags: drupal, .htaccess

I am moving my drupal 6/gallery2 site from Windows to Dreamhost (with Apache)
I've installed drupal and gallery and everything appears to be working.

I also have a list of static redirects. I am trying to add them to the default.htaccess (that drupal created) and it isn't working.

I want to redirect "example.com/drupal/99/foo.htm" to "example.com/drupal/bars/1999/foobar" (which is a clean url that needs to be rewritten by a drupal rewrite rule)

I first tried a rewrite rule (which is how I have it on the old server)
    RewriteRule ^/drupal/99/foo.htm$ /drupal/bars/1999/foobar[NC,R=301]

This didn't do anything.
Then I tried a redirect:

```
Redirect 301 /drupal/99/foo.htm /drupal/bars/1999/foobar
```

This almost works, but I get "/drupal/bars/1999/foobar?q=/drupal/99/foo.htm" which of course now throws a 404.
I'm not sure what is causing the q= as the only rule I see that does something is the Drupal rule:
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
Of course this seems to imply the drupal rule is run, then the redirect happens. I want the redirect to happen, then the drupal rule to rewrite the url.

What I want:
User enters example.com/drupal/99/foo.htm
is redirected to example.com/drupal/bars/1999/foobar
But actual url is example.com/index.php/q=bars/1999/foobar

Comment: you need to switch your first rewrite rule around `RewriteRule ^/drupal/bars/1999/foobar$ /drupal/99/foo.htm [NC,R=301]`

Comment: I thought the general concept was "RewriteRule old new" That is if the url matches old it gets rewritten to new. the foo.htm is the old address, the foobar is the new drupal clean url. I did try this, and it didn't seem to work either.